# Returning an amount

Tags: c#

In this code snippet, I want to be able to return the `Amount` as it is, unless the `CashFlowTypeID` is 12, 13, 14 or 15, in which case I want to return `Amount`, but negated.

How can this code snippet be improved? (Would you consider bitwise operations?)

```
public decimal GetAmount(decimal Amount, int CashFlowTypeID)
{
    if (new int[] { 12, 13, 14, 15 }.Contains(CashFlowTypeID))
    {
        Amount = Math.Abs(Amount) * -1;
    }
    else
    {
        Amount = Math.Abs(Amount);
    }
    return Amount;
}
```

Comment: Please, provide review/comment for downvotes!

Comment: Please add a short description about what your code is doing. Also explain why are you thinking about bitwise operations? And what's the importance of 12, 13, 14 and 15 ?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg, not all of the source code needs to be explined. This is not a Complex data structure that needs comments on every method.
tell me the line you do not understand please...

Comment: @levi It's not that the code is not understood.  It's that the question is made significantly better when a plain-English description of it is included.  Moreover, having a plain-English description can sometimes highlight a discepency between the code you've written and the code you think you've written.

Comment: "not all of the source code needs to be explined." You are not the judge of what needs to be explained or not. We need an explanation to do our jobs.

Comment: I don't have a problem understanding the lines at all, I just feel that all code snippets, no matter how simple they are, deserves a bit of explanation to make better quality Code Review questions. If there was a short explanation about what the code does, it would be even easier and quicker to understand your code. If you would  In this case, I have more problems understanding *why* you are doing it than *what* you are doing.

Comment: nhgrif, upvote for good points!

@DanPantry, read about code commenting
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111563/whats-the-golden-code-comment-ratio#answer-111574

Comment: @levi that concerns *comments in code*. We are asking for background information on your question. And for what it is worth `GetAmount` is **very** vague and I have no idea what it is for. `GetAmount` of what? What's the significance of your magic numbers?

Comment: @levi No one is asking for comments in code.  We're asking for a plain-English description of your code.

Comment: @levi that just repeats what the code does, which is trivial from inspection. **Why** are you doing that? What is special about those numbers? This is the problem with reviewing out-of-context snippets; how can we possibly give high-quality feedback without understanding the design? It looks like an enumerator would make the code clearer, for example, but without more information it's hard to say.

Comment: Why don't you do `if (12 <=  CashFlowTypeID <= 15){`

Answer (score 12):

I'm not a C# expert, but I can't imagine unnecessarily creating an array just to use `.Contains` is very efficient... nor can I imagining even using `.Contains` is particularly efficient.

I can't imagine anyway in which bitwise operations would be useful here given the current values.

---

#### To comment, or not to comment.  That is the question.

Or is it.

In the comments, you've linked to this question on StackOverflow to explain your lack of comments: [What's the golden code/comment ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111563/whats-the-golden-code-comment-ratio#answer-111574)

Personally, I tend to agree with the point Brad Wilson makes in his answer (not completely, but at least partially), but that doesn't mean everyone is exempt from writing clean, clear, understandable code.  Importantly, because one answer with 41 upvotes says "comments should be rare" doesn't mean your code devoid of comments is "doin' it right!".

Before we can graduate to rare comments, we must first be writing self-documenting code.  Your code is far from self-documenting.

Here are the following questions I scratch my head over when looking at this method:

1. Why is a method called `GetAmount` expecting an `amount` to be passed in?
2. After looking at the body, why are we doing any of this?  We don't we define `amount` elsewhere in our code to be an unsigned int and take steps to ensure it's always unsigned?  `decimal` is a signed type... more and more and more headscratching with why this method even exists at all...
3. What's special about 12, 13, 14, and 15?  Why not 1, 2, 3, and 4?  Why not any other set of numbers?  Why are there four?  Could there be more in the future?  Could there be less?  What's the likelihood of this set of numbers changing?
4. What are the other possible valid values for `cashFlowTypeId`?  `int` has a range of -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.  Are all of these values (except 12, 13, 14, and 15) valid values that should return a positive number for `amount`?  Or is this an oversight, and numerous values should be throwing an exception?

Until your code can begin to answer these questions *without* comments, your code *needs* comments.  I'm not suggesting you add comments.  I'm suggesting making your source code capable of answering these questions.  That might mean simply creating `enums` and `const` variables and finding better names for variables and methods.  It might mean adding `//comments`.  It doesn't matter.  The point is, your code leaves a maintainer asking a lot of questions and having to do a lot of research before anything is changed, and you need to correct that.

---

#### Code written on fewer lines is not more efficient for the compiler OR the maintainer.

Why don't we just use a `switch`?

```
public decimal GetAmount(decimal amount, int cashFlowTypeId)
{
    var rtnAmount = Math.Abs(amount);
    switch (cashFlowTypeId) {
        case 12:
        case 13:
        case 14:
        case 15:
            return rtnAmount * -1;
        default:
            return rtnAmount;
    }
}
```

It's not one line, but is more readable and more efficient.

---

#### Magic numbers, pulled from a hat.

Finally, `12`, `13`, `14`, and `15` and [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).  These should be named constants so that this method makes more sense to people with less context.

---

#### Bitwise operators.

I don't know how much control you have over the `cashFlowTypeId`, nor do I know how many `cashFlowTypeId`s there are.  However, if we have plenty of control over this aspect, we can make this method both more efficient *and* shorter with carefully chosen numbers.

Consider that an `int` is 32-bit in C#, I believe.  This means using only individual bits, we can signify 32 different cash flow types.  Is this enough?  We could change to a `long` and get 64-bits.  Is this enough?  Or can we use negative numbers?  Negative IDs can signify cash flow types that should return negative, and positive can signify cash flow types that should return positive.

If we use the negative/positive idea and treat `0` as non-negative, we could simply do:

```
public decimal GetAmount(decimal amount, int cashFlowTypeId)
{
    return Math.Abs(amount) * ((cashFlowTypeId >= 0) ? 1 : -1);
}
```

It's one line, but still perfectly readable and perfectly efficient.

Alternatively, if we're certain the number of cash flow types is limited, let's actually use a bitwise operator.

But first, to make things easier on ourselves, let's create an `enum` and define the different IDs.

```
enum CashFlowType
{
    None = 0 << 0;
    DebitAccountA = 1 << 0;
    DebitAccountB = 1 << 1;
    DebitAccountC = 1 << 2;
    CreditAccountA = 1 << 3;
    CreditAccountB = 1 << 4;
    CreditAccountC = 1 << 5;
}
```

And we just keep adding to this `enum` as necessary.  If we're going to use bitwise operations however, it's important that every value only takes a single bit (in the correct position) to represent.

We *might* consider special cases to represent the types that should be negative versus the types that should be positive.

For example:

```
DebitAccounts = DebitAccountA | DebitAccountB | DebitAccountC
CreditAccounts = CreditAccountA | CreditAccountB | CreditAccountC
```

So now, let's use some bitwise operators.

```
public decimal GetAmount(decimal amount, CashFlowType cashFlowType)
{
    // assuming we didn't make a special case for it in our enum:
   CashFlowType creditAccounts = CreditAccountA | CreditAccountB | CreditAccountC;

    return Math.Abs(amount) * ((cashFlowType & creditAccounts) ? -1 : 1);
}
```

Comment: +1 for "It's not one line, but is more readable". The size of someone's code in terms of line rarely matters. What really matters is the the ability for other programmers understand your code without going through mental gymnastics.

Comment: *"Until your code can begin to answer these questions without comments, your code needs comments."* < that is an excellent point well made.

Answer (score 2):

No need for the else, as if the If statement is true, return value.

```
public decimal GetAmount(decimal Amount, int CashFlowTypeID)
{
    if (new int[] { 12, 13, 14, 15 }.Contains(CashFlowTypeID))
    {
        return Math.Abs(Amount) * -1;
    }
       return Math.Abs(Amount);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would remove capital letters from variables (just for convention), not use explicit array typing if you are only using ints and perform operations you perform every time (`Math.Abs(amount)`) outside of a conditional check.

```
    public decimal GetAmount(decimal amount, int cashFlowTypeId)
    {
        var absAmount = Math.Abs(amount);

        if (new [] { 12, 13, 14, 15 }.Contains(cashFlowTypeId))
        {
            return absAmount * -1;
        }

        return absAmount;
    }
```

Comment: Answers should contain information on what, and why, it was changed. A simple code sample does not suffice.

Comment: I was writing that as you downvoted! :P

Comment: Why did you submit an incomplete answer then? ;-) I'll retract my downvote

Answer (score -2):

In addition to @enkapsulate's answer, you can even get it onto one line:

```
public decimal GetAmount(decimal Amount, int CashFlowTypeID)
    {
        return new int[] { 12, 13, 14, 15 }.Contains(CashFlowTypeID) ? Math.Abs(Amount) * -1 : Math.Abs(Amount);
    }
```

Comment: -1 : code review doesn't stand for one liners but for readable good code.

Comment: You can also get rid of the duplicated `Math.Abs` call: `return Math.Abs(Amount) * (new int[] { 12, 13, 14, 15 }.Contains(CashFlowTypeID) ? -1 : 1)`;

Comment: @chillworld You'll find that single line if statements are actually more efficient than regular if statements. They may not be as easy to read, however they are certainly faster.

Comment: `.Contains()` is a O(N) operation. Any performance gains from using a ternary operator (there are none, by the way) would be dwarfed by the time it takes to create a new array and then do an O(N) operation on it. Further, the goal of a programmer is to primarily write legible code first, and only optimize when absolutely necessary.

Comment: Ternary operators are not faster unless you're writing in a language like Objective-C or Swift which have a special version of the operator that can avoid duplicated method calls.

Comment: @MikeEason if you are worried about efficient code why not putting the int array as constant. Creating every time a new array costs.